# Android: MediaRouteButton not detecting chromecast on some devices?

Tags: android, chromecast, mediarouter

I have an issue where MediaRouteButton is not detecting chromecast on some devices.
It's being detected on the older phone Samsung Galaxy Nexus, but not on my Google Pixel.

The funny thing is it used to work on my Google Pixel, but now it's not working anymore. On my pixel, I checked wifi multiple times and YouTube chromecast works, just not my app.

I checked the sample MediaRouterButton demo and it's not working either. https://github.com/googlecast/MediaRouter-Cast-Button-android

The callback doesn't seem to be triggered.

```
mMediaRouter.addCallback(mChromecastDeviceSelector,
    mMediaRouterCallback, 
    MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_REQUEST_DISCOVERY);
```

EDIT:
I tested on N and O and it didn't work. However the N and O device and the same Google Play Services version (11.7.46). The Samsung Galaxy Nexus has Jellybean but an older Google Play Services version (10.2.98)

EDIT2: Looks like it's working again after the weekend, dunno what happened. :/

EDIT3: It's NOT working again.

Comment: Is this only happening on devices running Android O?

Comment: @LeonNicholls I tested on N and it also didn't work. However the N and O device and the same Google Play Services version.